# Why my test net transactions (created from dart using web3dart) are not getting through?

Tags: transactions, ether, dapps

I have used web3dart to create a few ethereum transactions. All of them are getting stuck in pending.

For example:
https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/tx/0x70255a850f8929052d838545d94851bcec34c26cac3916ec75daf77f664a1eba
https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/tx/0xdfac33c04b8be256166a7609a4fe0961061aa78950f732828e5f702fdde28792

Here's the code that i have used to make these transactions:

```
  var apiUrl =
      "https://polygon-mumbai.infura.io/v3/fc4ab81....<full url here>"; 

  var httpClient = Client();
  var ethClient = Web3Client(apiUrl, httpClient);

  String res = await ethClient.sendTransaction(
    credentials,
    Transaction(
      to: EthereumAddress.fromHex("0xf0725F1c0e651B9aBF91814bc4eE28922f54AC9b"),
      gasPrice: EtherAmount.inWei(BigInt.from(20000000000)),
      maxGas: 10000000,
      value: EtherAmount.fromBase10String(EtherUnit.gwei, "2000000"),
    ),
    chainId: 80001,
  );
  print("Token send result = $res");
```

Please help me find the issue here.